# How to set password strength indicator on password_confirm element

Tags: 7, forms, users

How to add the Drupal password strength indicator to a custom password_confirm fapi element like this one :

```
  $form['pass'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password_confirm',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

Comment: It should happen automatically, just for the fact the `password_confirm` element has [`user_form_process_password_confirm `](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/7) as a process function. Have you tried it?

Comment: Maybe it is because I use a ctools multistep form, it doesn't work. I worked around the problem by using the same js as in the original form in #attached.